# No se codifica imagen

Tags: php, base-de-datos, imagen

estoy haciendo un buscador con php, en el cual tambien deben de aparecer los datos de lo que se busca, y los entre los datos de lo que se busca debe aparecer una imagen, pero primero ocupo adquirir la imagen y transformarla/codificarla, pero no se codifica.

-SEARCH.PHP-

```
<?php 
if(!isset($_POST['search'])) exit('No se recibió el valor a buscar');

require_once 'conexion.php';

function search()
{
  $mysqli = getConnexion();
  $search = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['search']);
  $query = "SELECT nombre, id, Imagen FROM tabla_imagen WHERE nombre LIKE '%$search%' ";
  $res = $mysqli->query($query);
  $html=""; while ($row = $res->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) { $img=base64_encode($row["Imagen"]); $html.="<p><a
  href=\"$row[nombre]\" target=\"_blank\">$row[nombre]</a> <a href=\"$row[Imagen]\"
  target=\"_blank\">$row[Imagen]</a> <a href=\"$row[Imagen]\"
  target=\"_blank\">$row[nombre]</a> <a><img height=\"80px\" src=\"data:image/jpg;base64,
  $img\"></a></p>"; } echo $html;
}

search();
```

Comment: Para que una `<table>` se muestre tienes que escribirla completa: `<table><tr><td>Contenido</td></tr></table>`  ¿Lo estás haciendo así? Otra cosa es que organices el lío en tu código. El `echo` lo cierras aquí con el punto y coma: `</p>";` y luego abres esto estando en un bloque PHP, lo cual resultará en un error: `<tr>
          <td><img height="80px" src="data:image/jpg;base64,<?php echo base64_encode($row['Imagen']); ?>"/></td>
          </tr>` evita esas confusas mezclas concatenando en una sola variable.

Comment: Espera, voy a editar mi codigo y me dices que tal, porque ya no lo quiero ordenar en una tabla ;)

Comment: Sigues teniendo un lío de comillas y bloques HTML/PHP que da miedo. Yo me refería a algo como esto: `$html="";  
  while ($row = $res->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $img=base64_encode($row["Imagen"]);
    $html.="<p><a href=\"$row[nombre]\" target=\"_blank\">$row[nombre]</a>
      <a href=\"$row[Imagen]\" target=\"_blank\">$row[Imagen]</a>
   <a href=\"$row[Imagen]\" target=\"_blank\">$row[nombre]</a>
   <a><img height=\"80px\ src=\"data:image/jpg;base64, $img\"></a></p>";      
  }
  echo $html;` Ya haciendo eso se ven cosas muy raras, como por ejemplo...

Comment: ... ¿Qué hay en la columna `Imagen` de tu base de datos, es un BLOB o qué es? ¿Por qué usas ese dato en el `href`, y además lo usas varias veces de una forma algo extraña y hasta inconsciente diría yo? ¿Por qué tienes tres anchortags que parecen casi idénticos? Etc, etc, etc. Si no te funciona, haz un `var_dump($row);` para depurar, cuando viene a ver ni siquiera tienes datos en tu consulta.

Comment: Sip, tengo mi codigo se me hizo bolas, pero mira, en efecto tengo datos tipo BLOB, el href es para que cuando presiones un dato te lleve a una tabla que voy a hacer, y tambien para eso son los anchortags

Comment: Faltó una comilla, este es el código corregido: `$html=""; while ($row = $res->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) { $img=base64_encode($row["Imagen"]); $html.="<p><a href=\"$row[nombre]\" target=\"_blank\">$row[nombre]</a> <a href=\"$row[Imagen]\" target=\"_blank\">$row[Imagen]</a> <a href=\"$row[Imagen]\" target=\"_blank\">$row[nombre]</a> <a><img height=\"80px\" src=\"data:image/jpg;base64, $img\"></a></p>"; } echo $html;` OJO, esta es sólo la parte del `while`.

Comment: Prueba el código corregido, se me olvidó una comilla en el height. Y en cuanto a lo que comentas, no es normal poner un BLOB  en el `href` como veo que haces ¿? De todos modos prueba como te sugiero en el penúltimo comentario y di si funciona a no, o qué muestra en pantalla.

Comment: Joven, actualmente mi codigo es como lo acabo de editar, y no, aun no codifica la imagen, me muestra muchos carcteres raros.

Comment: Espere, ya me aparecen las imagenes codificadas, tenia un error, estapa imprimiendo 2 veces la imagen

Comment: ¿Ya funciona entonces?

Comment: Efectivamente, muchas gracias por la ayuda :D.

Comment: Una ultima duda, habrá alguna manera de que solo muestre los nombres y el id y hasta que yo presione el nombre , el id, o lo que sea aparezca la foto, porque estoy teniendo problemas porque las fotos no cargan porque pesan mucho

Comment: A mi entender lo veo complicado, porque la URL es la misma imagen y necesita ser codificada in situ, no veo forma de guardar sólo el BLOB y luego pasarlo a otro sitio para que se abra allí, y tampoco creo que ganes en rapidez, pues lo pesado en sí es el BLOB y tienes que traerlo en la consulta y manipularlo. Una cosa que puedes hacer es usar otra lógica, por ejemplo mediante Ajax mandas a buscar los datos (excluyendo el BLOB), construyes los enlaces en base a los otros datos y cuando se haga clic se lanza una nueva consulta para buscar únicamente el BLOB sobre el dato en que se hizo click.

Comment: Espero que me entiendas..Que opinas de la opcion de hacer que el id sea una palabra linkeable y que al hacerle click que te mande a otro index que solo este haciendo el request a la imagen?

Comment: A eso me refiero, a usar el `id` como un link o lo que tú quieras y cuando se haga click en ese link se lance otra petición que traiga la imagen específica de ese id solamente, es lo lógico, pues si tienes varias imágenes pesadas, no vas a traerlas todas sin saber si se van a usar todas, pues eso ralentiza la página. Y, si lo haces con Javascript/Ajax ni siquiera hace falta abrir otra página para mostrar la imagen, puedes traerla y mostrarla en un contenedor de la misma página, sin refrescar ni nada. Además, Javascript tiene una API muy buena para manejar contenido BLOB.

Answer (score 5):

Para resolver el problema de que no se muestra la imagen, sugiero que evites la constante mezcla de bloques PHP/HTML, que produce en estos casos un código ilegible y complicado de depurar. Terminas perdido entre tantos `" > ' <?php ?> echo "'"'"; <p> "Hola class='¿abriste o cerraste? <p></p> ?> <?php`

Acostumbra a escribir un código limpio, mediante unas técnicas muy básicas:

- Usar una sola variable para concatenarlo todo (en este caso esa variable es `$html`. Observa que se crea vacía primero y luego se concatena con el operador `.=`
- Rodear todo el contenido por comillas dobles `"`, porque eso nos permite usar variables dentro del bloque
- En ese contexto las claves de los arrays se pueden poner sin comillas, por ejemplo: `$row[Imagen]`
- Y las comillas dobles para etiquetas HTML que se usan con `href, class`, etc. se escapan con `\` antes de cada comilla doble.
- Los valores que puedan ser complicados (como es el caso de `$img`) sácalos aparte en una variable, y luego usa esa variable en la concatenación.
- Finalmente haz `echo` de  `$html`. Así evitas estar haciendo `echo... echo ... echo...` en medio de un lío de código que llega un momento que no sabes ni dónde estás.

Haciendo eso el código queda así:

```
  $html="";     
  while ($row = $res->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $img=base64_encode($row["Imagen"]);
    $html.="<p><a href=\"$row[nombre]\" target=\"_blank\">$row[nombre]</a>
            <a href=\"$row[Imagen]\" target=\"_blank\">$row[Imagen]</a>
            <a href=\"$row[Imagen]\" target=\"_blank\">$row[nombre]</a>
            <a><img height=\"80px\" src=\"data:image/jpg;base64, $img\"></a></p>";      
  }
  echo $html;
```

Este es un código fácilmente analizable ante cualquier fallo.

Con esto resuelves tu problema inicial. Todas las dudas que surjan posteriormente deben ser planteadas en otra pregunta. Ya viendo el código así, se ven varias anomalías, como el hecho de querer usar un BLOB como destino de una etiqueta `href`, o unos anchor tags que parecen redundantes... Eso es ya parte de la lógica de tu programa o de lo que quieras hacer, solamente te lo señalo.

Otro problema en tu código es que la consulta SQL que usas es vulnerable a ataques de Inyección SQL. El hecho de usar `real_escape_string` no te protege en todos los casos de inyeccción, deberías más bien usar consultas preparadas.

Comment: Muchas gracias por los consejos, intentare apegarme a ello